# Source not working inside while loop

Tags: bash

This is probably something very silly, but I cannot find any answers anywhere. I've tried to setup a `.bashrc.d` directory with scripts to source within `.bashrc`, to make the process more organised. Instead of manually sourcing each script in `.bashrc.d`, I'm sourcing them in this way:

```bsh
if [ -d "$HOME/.bashrc.d" ]; then
    find "$HOME/.bashrc.d/" -type f -name "*.sh" | sort | \
        while read -r f; do
            source "$f"
        done
fi
```

However, `source "$f"` seems to be running inside a subshell, because the command doesn't actually source any of the files. It executes them as I can see by the output of `set -x`, but e.g. none of the variable exports carry to the original iteractive shell. I also know this is a problem with sourcing inside the while loop and not with sourcing from `.bashrc`, since manually sourcing these files actually works (albeit it doesn't solve this issue). What is even happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have subfolders under ~/.bashrc.d? If not, `for f in "$HOME/.bashrc.d"/*.sh` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the pipes and not the `while` that make the command run in subshell. Setting the `lastpipe` option doesn't help in an interactive shell with job control.
Try a "process substitution" ( should your `bash` version provide that):

```
while read -r f; do source "$f"; done < <( find "$HOME/.bashrc.d/" -type f -name "*.sh" | sort )
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right that you run `source` in a subshell. To fix it you can
simply loop through the files without piping output of find:

```
for script in "$HOME"/.bashrc.d/*.sh
do
    if [ -r "$script" ]
    then
        . "$script"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the glob is also sorted by default, giving similar results as `find | sort`. Though the glob wouldn't look into subdirectories of `.bashrc.d/`, but then I'm not sure if that's usually done for `.d` directories anyway.